# How can I add files to rebol3 startup (in the compiled executable)?

Tags: rebol, rebol3

In **os/host-main.c** there's this line

```
 n = RL_Start((REBYTE *)(&Reb_Init_Code[0]), REB_INIT_SIZE, 0); // TRUE on halt
```

in **include/host-init.h** I found

```
const unsigned char Reb_Init_Code[REB_INIT_SIZE] = {
    "\x78\x9C\xD5\x1A\x59\x73\xDB\xC6\xB9\xCF\xFB\x2B\x56\xF0\x74\x2C"
... }
```

and then, there's **tools/make-host-init.r** which creates *include/host-init.h* and *boot/host-init.r*

I have added a file to the files list in **make-host-init.r** which just sets a word to a string, and prints the string. Then I have

```
make clean
make
```

but in the newly created r3 executable this seems not to be present (though I've seen that the files have been altered).

Is there anything else I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

If you are modifying the Rebol code, you need to run `make prep` as well because that runs all the Rebol scripts.

If you are adding a file, you probably need to add it to `os/tools/file-base.r` (and since it is a rebol file, run `make prep` afterwards.

You probably also want to remake the make file for you machine (`make make OS_ID=X.X.X`)